how do I get postmessage from webview in flutter web and android
I am making an app where which shows an iframe content, so I am using an IFrameElement and HtmlElementView for the web which works, but the android part using webview_flutter not working
Working web part
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowView({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShowView> createState() => _ShowViewState();
}

class _ShowViewState extends State<ShowView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    //setup listener ---------------------------------
    window.addEventListener("message", (Event event) {
      String? data = (event as MessageEvent).data.toString();
      print('message: $data');
    });
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'test-view-type',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..height = '500'
        ..width = '500'
        ..src = '<URL>'
        ..style.border = 'none',
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const HtmlElementView(
      viewType: 'test-view-type',
    );
  }
}


Not working android part
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ShowView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowView({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShowView> createState() => _ShowViewState();
}

class _ShowViewState extends State<ShowView> {
  late WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'message',
        onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
          print('channel Message: $message');
        },
      )
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse(
          '<URL>',
        ),
      );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebViewWidget(controller: controller);
  }
}


The Iframe is giving the data like this
window.parent.postMessage(data,'*');

For web I am window.addEventListener which works, for android I am trying addJavaScriptChannel which is not working
I want to listen to the messages from both web and android

Hi @myme, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you edit your question to mention how is it not your working? What do you see happening?

As I mentioned in web view it is working, but the onMessageReceived in the addJavaScriptChannel(android) not triggered
